# Выполнение php переменных в другой переменной

Tags: php, форма

Есть переменная, содержащая обычную веб-форму:

```
$petform = "
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$path\" id=\"contactform\">
<div>
<label for=\"name\"><strong>Имя:</strong></label><br/>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\" value=\"$name\" />
</div>

.....

<div>           
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Отправить\" name=\"submit\" />
</div>

</form>";
```

Проблема в том что надо каким-то образом вставить в эту же переменную следующий код:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "57tertwrfs67632462ywr445y"; 
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Так чтобы он исполнялся в самой переменной, выводящей форму. Это реально?

```
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически реально, практически - зачем?

Разве вот такого недостаточно?

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "57tertwrfs67632462ywr445y"; 
$petform = "
<form method=\"post\" action=\"$path\" id=\"contactform\">
...
".recaptcha_get_html($publickey)."
</form>";
```

P.S. по теме посмотрите "функцию" [eval()](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Но в данном случае, повторюсь, постарайтесь от нее воздержаться.

Comment: Похоже, что недостаточно, ибо так значение `$publickey` не отдается в переменную с формой, соответственно на странице, где осуществляется вывод формы не все работает, так как не все данные переданы. 

(Наверное, надо было уточнить, что переменная с формой хранится в функции, поэтому надо как-то передавать в форму и 
`    $publickey = "57tertwrfs67632462ywr445y";` 
)